# Clustering dates into periods

Tags: sql, algorithm, date, cluster-analysis, date-range

**The Problem**
I have a list of Keys and another list of Dates for each of these keys. Basically a Multimap of Keys to Dates (in Java, `Multimap<Key, Date>`). I use these Keys and Dates to query a table  like this:

```
select * from Table where key = :key and date = :date
```

This is horrible performance wise as `Σ(|Date(Key)|)` queries are generated. To improve this I can look at querying on periods in the form of:

```
select * from Table where key in (:keys) and date >= :startDate and date <= :endDate
```

As such only one query is required, but there is still a performance problem in that these dates can differ by very large periods (years). As example take a basic case where there are two Keys, with the first having a Date of '2010-01-01' assigned and the second a date of '2012-01-01'. In that case this query will return all values between that period, even though I only need two records.

**Solution Approach**
Ideally I'd like to generate the optimal number of queries, where the optimum is a function on the number of queries and the amount of data returned. I'd like as few queries as possible, but in such a way that they return the least amount of unnecessary data. Put another way, a simple fitness function could be `w|Queries| x |Data|`, where `w` is some weight.

Given this the previous example will result in two queries, whereas if the dates were close together it would only be a single query.

**Options**
This seems like a clustering problem, but I don't have much knowledge on clustering and as such I'm not really sure where to start. I guess that I'd probably have to break the Multimap into individuals of the form `(Key, Date)`, and from there look for an algorithm that identifies the number of clusters itself.

Is there any clustering algorithm or approach that is well suited to my problem, or is there perhaps a solution other than clustering?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IN`:

```
select * from Table where key = :key and date IN (date1, date2, date3, etc.)
```

With it you can select the desired dates all at once.

Comment: I agree that this will be sufficient for most cases, but there are cases that I have to address where some form of clustering could be beneficial. Take for example if there are 10,000 keys distributed across 10 dates. With clustering the system will (hopefully) decide to generate 10 SQL queries resulting in 10,000 records, whereas your query will return 100,000 records (if you replace the key = :key portion with key in (:keys)).

Comment: Add your info into a `#temp table` and make an inner join it and your table.